# Polymer point-overlay click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polymer

Following this guide I could run the project correctly, now I want to add an event for the points drawn. So this is my code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>PolymerVizCodelab</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/point-overlay/point-overlay.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-slider/paper-slider.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="t">
    <google-map map="{{map}}" latitude="38.6" longitude="-95.8" zoom="5"
      styles='[{"stylers":[{"saturation":-85}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"lightness":-20}]}]'
      on-google-map-ready="setPointSize"
      on-zoom-changed="setPointSize">
    </google-map>
    <point-overlay on-click="clickHandler" map="[[map]]" uniforms="{{uniforms}}" data="{{data}}" id="p">
    </point-overlay>
    <iron-ajax auto handle-as="json"
      url="bower_components/point-overlay/tornadoes-1950-2014.json"
      last-response="{{data}}">
    </iron-ajax>

    <!-- <paper-card elevation="2">
      <paper-slider min="5" max="100" value="30"></paper-slider>
    </paper-card> -->
  </template>

  <script>
    var t = document.querySelector('#t');
    t.setPointSize = function(e) {
      this.uniforms.pointSize = Math.exp(0.3 * this.map.getZoom());
      this.notifyPath('uniforms.pointSize', this.uniforms.pointSize);
    };
    function clickHandler(e) {
      console.log("click");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the `clickHandler` is never fired.

How can I bind and event for each point on the map?

Answer (score 1):

`clickHandler` needs to be part of the `dom-bind` template (like you've done with `setPointSize`). Change this:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
  console.log("click");
}
```

to this:

```
t.clickHandler = function(e) {
  console.log("click");
};
```

Comment: I only changed that function but it does not show anything. The `point-overlay` does not need to has a method for click or picking?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `point-overlay` does not expose any events, in addition the  [`CanvasLayer`](https://github.com/brendankenny/CanvasLayer) map layer which is used by `point-overlay` to visualize data on Google Maps prevents mouse events to trigger event listeners.

But with a few modifications applied to [polymer-webgl-visualization component](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/polymer-webgl-visualization) it could be acomplished as shown below:

In `canvas-layer.js` file:

1) comment the line that prevents mouse events to trigger event listeners in overlay element  (`CanvasLayer`):

```
canvas.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

Modify `point-overlay` element (`point-overlay.html` file)

2)set map pane to `overlayMouseTarget`

```
this.overlay.setPaneName("overlayMouseTarget");
```

3)introduce `click` event handler for canvas element:

```
var me = this;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.overlay.canvas, 'click', function() {
     me.fire('overlay-click');
});
```

And finally in `index.html` file:

4) register `clickHandler` event handler

```
<point-overlay on-overlay-click="clickHandler" map="[[map]]" uniforms="{{uniforms}}" data="{{data}}" id="p">
</point-overlay>
```

where

```
var t = document.querySelector('#t');
t.clickHandler = function(e) {
   console.log('clicked');
};
```

[**Working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/u99Mc3iLLOGGgMXk4bvS?p=preview)

Comment: Hello I liked your approach, but when I click anywhere on the map I have an alert, but I only need it when a point is clicked